# Emacs org-mode: clocktable configuration

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I know that I can generate a clocktable running C c C c on the block:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 4 :scope file
#+END:
```

or with the key combination:

```
C c C x C r.
```

However, the latter, generates a clocktable with:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 2 :scope subtree
```

(I want a block like the other one, with maxlevel 4.). How can I config the C c C x C r combination?e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set

```
(setq org-clock-clocktable-default-properties '(:maxlevel 4 :scope file))
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work completely. It does set :maxlevel 4, but keeps :scope subtree.

Comment: It's still the same line... :( Somehow .emacs doesn't use the :scope file setting.

Comment: Wait, it was correct last time. You need to upgrade your emacs.

Comment: I already have GNU Emacs 24.2.1. And this is the last in the Ubuntu repository.

Comment: I've got 24.3.4 compiled from source. The procedure is as easy as untar, configure, make and make install.
The solution surely works for my system.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34298/discussion-between-xyz-and-abo-abo)